# How to send test results to InfluxDB

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, grafana

I currently have a set of tests (Selenium/UI). I want to send test result metrics to Grafana. I am thinking of sending the test results to the Influx database and redirecting them to Grafana at the end. Where do I start?